# Convert enum? to int? fails when using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

It succeed when using `int?` to convert.
It failed when using reflection to convert.
How can I assign value `enum?` to property `int?` successful using reflection?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dc dc = new Dc { Solution = Solution.Upgrade };

    Model model = new Model {  };

    //assign by reflection
    var psolution = model.GetType().GetProperty("Solution");
    //psolution.SetValue(model, dc.Solution); //this fail
    model.Solution = (int?)dc.Solution; //this success
    psolution.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(dc.Solution, psolution.PropertyType)); //this fail
}

class Dc
{
    public Solution? Solution { get; set; }
}

class Model
{
    public int? Solution { get; set; }
}

enum Solution
{
    Upgrade = 1,
    Discard = 2,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(psolution.PropertyType) ?? psolution.PropertyType;
object safeValue = (dc.Solution == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(dc.Solution, t);
property.SetValue(model, safeValue, null);
```

You need to get the underlying type parameter of `Nullable<T>` in order to set the value for the `int?`.